# Converting multiple divs into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've created a module for the WPBakery plugin which allows a user to drag and drop a `tab item` into the tab container. Just a visual of what I'm referring to:

[image]

The outer container will generate the parent and ul class, then for each new `Tab Item` added, it will generate a new `.tab__item` class, which for me houses a header and an image.

The pseudo for a `.tab__item` is the following:

```html
<div class="tab__item">

  <div class="tabbedContent__left">
    <!-- header will be here -->
  </div>
  
  <div class="tabbedContent__right">
  <!-- image will be as a background image on this div -->
  </div>
  
</div>
```

When a `header` is hovered upon, the `.tabbedContent__right` will show the according image under that `.tab__item`.

The issue I'm having is that for each new `Tab Item` that is added in the backend, it will generate a new `.tab__item` div which obviously has its own `.tabbedContent__right` div. This means that when a new header is hovered upon, the `.tabbedContent__right` div shifts down.

It's probably better explained with a demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.tabs__li .header').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('.tab__item').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('active');
  })

  // add class .active on li hover
  $('.tabs__li').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.tab__item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.tab__item').addClass('active');
  });

  // Change active tab every x seconds
  $(function() {
    var list = $(".tab__item"),
    currentActive = 0;
    time = 5; //interval in seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        currentActive = (currentActive + 1) % list.length;
        list.removeClass('active').eq(currentActive).addClass('active');
    }, time * 1000);
  });

})
```

```css
.tabbedContent ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tabbedContent__left, 
.tabbedContent__right {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

.tabbedContent__left {
    margin: 0;
}
.tabbedContent__left .tabs__li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.tabbedContent__left .tabs__li span.header {
    font-size: 2.313rem;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-bold", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ABABAB;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabbedContent .tab__item.active .tabbedContent__left li.tabs__li span.header {
    color: #454544;
}

.tabbedContent__right {
    display: none;
    min-height: 325px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.tabbedContent .tab__item.active .tabbedContent__right {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="tabbedContent">
  <ul class="tabs d-flex flex-column">

    <!-- container for 1 -->
    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row active">
      <div class="tabbedContent__left">
        <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-1">
          <span class="header"> Header </span>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="tabbedContent__right" id="tab-1'" style="background-image:url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/5a50me.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <!--------->
    
    <!-- container for 2 -->
    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row active">
      <div class="tabbedContent__left">
        <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-2">
          <span class="header"> Header 2 </span>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="tabbedContent__right" id="tab-2'" style="background-image:url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/2zdr4f7.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <!--------->
    
        <!-- container for 3 -->
    <div class="tab__item d-flex flex-column flex-md-row active">
      <div class="tabbedContent__left">
        <li class="tabs__li" data-tab="tab-3">
          <span class="header"> Header 3 </span>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="tabbedContent__right" id="tab-3'" style="background-image:url(http://oi68.tinypic.com/5a50me.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
    <!--------->

  </ul>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/n84c7150/2/)

As you can see with the above demo, the height (and presence of multiple) `.tabbedContent__right` divs, is causing a gap between the headers.

**What I want to do:**

I cannot alter the markup structure (i.e. `tab__item` must have `tabbedContent__left` and `tabbedContent__right`). But I don't want multiple `.tabbedContent__right` divs to be generated, **only the one**. So something like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can manipulate my current markup to only show one but still function as it does in the demo via JS?

**More info:**

***What does the JS that creates the divs look like?***

I haven't created any JS for this (because I wasn't sure if it was the best approach). All my JS regarding this module is in the demo above.

***After I drag and drop a tab item into the container, what happens?***

This is how the backend of the module looks like:

[image]

When a `Tab Item` is added, the following markup is generated:

```
<div class="tab__item">

  <div class="tabbedContent__left">
    <span class="header">' . $tab_header . '</span>
  </div>

  <div class="tabbedContent__right" style="background-image:url('.$background_img.');"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I understand visually what your problem is, but I'm a little confused on how you want to solve it. Do you want to modify the JS that inserts the `.tab__item` divs, or do you just want some kind of workaround with JS/CSS to toggle the background image in one of the `.tabbedContent__right` divs while the others remain hidden all the time so it *looks* different than the markup actually is?

Comment: @cjl750 - I almost want to hide all the `.tabbedContent__right` divs and then create another div (let's call it `.tabbedContent__overview`) via JS. The `tabbedContent__overview` div will then be `100%` height (matching how many headers are generated), but still function the same. So when I hover over `header 1` , `tabbedContent__overview` will show the red circle, when hovering over `header 2`, `tabbedContent__overview` will show me the yellow circle. Do you think that's the best approach?

Comment: I think there are multiple ways you could solve your problem. That would be one. A CSS workaround is another. Modifying the JS that creates the divs in the first place is yet another. But before anyone can provide much meaningful help, we'd need to know 1. What does the JS that creates the divs look like (i.e., after I drag and drop a tab item into the container, what happens?), and 2. How is the background image determined? Is that inline style added as part of the process of creating the divs or does it come from somewhere else? You'll need to update your question with more info.

Comment: @cjl750 - I've updated my question, hopefully that answers all your queries